# A validation where "bet" shouldn't exceed the current wallet

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I have input type number = "BET" and a current wallet. My target is my "BET" shouldn't greater than what I have currently on my wallet. For example 600-700 = (Error, not enough balance). Thank you in advance.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#box").keyup( function(){
      var betAmount = $("#box").val();
      var walletAmount = 500; // your session data goes here <?php echo $_SESSION['currentWallet']?>
      var remainingAmount = walletAmount - betAmount;
      $("#betAmountResult").text(remainingAmount);
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="uname" id="box" required>
<p>YOUR BET:  <a class="p-1" id="betAmount"></a></p>
<!-- change id's name to betAmount -->
<p>CURRENT WALLET:   <a style="color:blue;">500</a></p>
<p class="remaining">REMAINING BALANCE:
<a class="p-1" id="betAmountResult"></a></p>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/684eu5wv/1/

Comment: Yes what you are saying/asking sounds sensible. You probably should write a function to check the condition before allowing submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code

```
<script>


 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#box").keyup( function(){
      var betAmount = $("#box").val();
      var walletAmount = 500; // your session data goes here <?php echo 
      $_SESSION['currentWallet']?>
      var remainingAmount = walletAmount - betAmount;
     $("#betAmountResult").text(remainingAmount >=0 ? remainingAmount : 'Error, not enough balance');
   })
 });
```